# Lambda expression to step backwards in a chain based on keys

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, lambda

```
KEY            NAME            REPLACED_BY
1              Foo 1.0         3
2              Bar 1.0         NULL
3              Foo 2.0         NULL
```

This is supposed to represent a database table with a `PRODUCT` table. The product entity has 3 properties, `KEY`, `NAME` and `REPLACED_BY`.

What I would like to know is that if I fetch a product from the context:

```
var product = context.PRODUCT.FirstOrDefault(p => p.KEY == 3);
```

Is there any way to use a Lambda expression to fetch all the previous versions of the products (using the `REPLACED_BY` field)? Or do I need to make a foreach-loop?

Comment: Without a `REPLACES` field, there's no way to tell without looping over the set.

Comment: @jbabey That's what the `REPLACED_BY` field does.

Comment: Right, but there's no link from a product to what other products it has replaced, which is what I imagined the `REPLACES` field to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have proper relationships in your database then you could access the previous one like so:

```
var lastProduct = product.Replaced;//or what ever you call your relationship
```

with that in mind you could create a function like this:

```
List<Product> GetPreviousProducts(Product current)
{
    List<Product> results = new List<Product>();

    Product previous = current.Replaced;

    while(previous != null)
    {
        results.Add(previous);
        previous = previous.Replaced;
    }

    return results;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I only have the key in my database table, but I suppose I can solve it by adding a property to the product entity poco class?

Comment: @Johan: not sure what you mean by that, I always work with the relationships in the DB and let the designer create the code. If you mean manually add in the relationship without touching the DB then yeah that should work fine

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you want to do, you may trying joining the table with itself like this: (I don't have anything to debug here so maybe take this with a pinch of salt)

```
var products = (from p in context.PRODUCT
                join r in context.PRODUCT on p.KEY == r.REPLACED_BY
                select r)
               .Union
               (from x in context.PRODUCT where x.KEY == 3 select x);
```

problem is that you have no way of getting only the products identified by the key unless you have another common identifier (like the name) and maybe keep the version number in a separate column.